Why does scrollLeft produce a positive number at direction:rtl
In touchscreen mode, set the attribute direction:rtl; At this point I manipulate the content of a piece of the overflow dom element to get the distance that the horizontal scrollbar scrolls.
According to the reasoning of the initial situation, it is not possible to move to the left, the value is from negative to 0, but I found that the initial situation can be moved to the left, and get the positive number of scrollLeft 0.666666666865348816
I just use demo to show my problem：

first of all,In touch screen mode, the element is styled and a selectable class name is set as shown belowenter image description here



const priceElement = document.querySelector('.testScrollLeft');
priceElement .scrollLeft
    width: 100%;
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: right;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
<h1 class="flex--item fl1 fs-headline1 testScrollLeft">
  Top Questions Top Questions Top Questions Top Questions Top Questions Top Questions Top Questions Top Questions Top Questions Top Questions
</h1>




Initially, I get a scrollLeft of 0, but then I realize that the scrollbar can be scrolled to the left, with the following scroll values
enter image description here
When I slide to the right to generate the scrollbar, and then I slide back to the original position, found that the value of scrollLeft will no longer be 0?
enter image description here



    const priceElement = document.querySelector('.testScrollLeft');


> priceElement .scrollLeft 0 
priceElement .scrollLeft
> 0.6666666865348816 
priceElement .scrollLeft
> 0.6666666865348816 
priceElement .scrollLeft
> 0.6666666865348816




Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Provide a proper [mre] of the issue.

Sorry, this is the first time I've asked a question and have added the relevant code
